Settings app crashes when windows event log is disabled
I was experiencing heavy input lag while playing GTA 5 on my pc and a stem thread recommended disabling windows event log in msconfig. That did fix the lag issue for me however, the network icon on the taskbar is gone and opening network settings crashes the settings app, I can still connect via wireless and ethernet though. Enabling windows event log back fixes this problem. Is it really the culprit or is there some other reason for the settings app crash? And is there any other way to remove the GTA5 input lag?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
